# Setting log file in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, classpath, logfile

I have set the log file in my eclipse project 
server-> open launch configuration->classpath->advance->external folder
but still logs are coming in console rather this file "elog.log"

Answer (score 1):

you need to do it this way

1. Right click on project
2. go to commons tab
3. uncheck **"Allocate Console"** and
4. select the file option providing the file where you want your
       re-directed output

hope this helps!

Good luck!

Comment: I wanted only logs should be redirected to log file but your answer redirect whole console output to this file. this does not answer my question but still i could work.